Should we allow hypothetical "what if" questions about legal consequences for characters?
There's a question (currently open) on the site: What charges/prison time would Jack Black realistically be looking at by the end of School of Rock?
This essentially asks for speculation on a hypothetical situation not depicted in the movie. In other words, it's a "What if ______ happened?" type of question, which the help center advises against asking: What types of questions should I avoid asking?
I voted to close this question because I believe it's both off-topic for this site and primarily opinion-based. The open-ended, hypothetical legal outcome would depend on various factors, like a judge or jury's interpretation of the law. While interesting to ponder, this falls more into the realm of jurisprudence than the stated scope of Movies & TV, which focuses on questions directly about movies and shows themselves.
Interestingly, though, a few other users, including a moderator, left it open in the review queue. And the OP even acknowledged that their question is speculative and arguably irrelevant, saying:

Lol, it's not opinion-based. Maybe speculative and sure, probably irrelevant but it's not opinion based. But feel free to close this 5 year old question. Keep on fightin' the good fight.

These are reasons to close a question as per the help center guidelines on what types of questions are allowed and not allowed here. Specifically:

Please note that the following subjects are considered off-topic here:


Opinions about […] a movie or TV show




To prevent your question from being flagged and possibly removed, avoid asking subjective questions where …
[…]

you are asking an open-ended, hypothetical question: “What if ______ happened?”

Some subjective questions are allowed, but “subjective” does not mean “anything goes”. All subjective questions are expected to be constructive. What does that mean? Constructive subjective questions:
[…]

invite sharing experiences over opinions


My concern is that leaving a question like this open could lead to more low-quality, speculative "what if" questions pondering hypothetical legal consequences for characters' actions, like "What charges would the gang from It's Always Sunny face after [insert episode plot summary]?"
I enjoy a fun thought experiment as much as anyone, but do we want to open the floodgates for this type of question on the main site? I think a line needs to be drawn to preserve quality and stick to our stated topicality guidelines. What are your thoughts? Should we allow these kinds of hypothetical legal questions or keep them off-topic?

We've closed similar hypothetical questions before
I think we have a clear precedent for closing questions like the one about the potential legal consequences for Jack Black's character in School of Rock.
Recently, the community decided to close a very similar question: In "Se7en", if two detectives refuse John's offer and he pleads insanity in court, will he succeed?
The issue with both questions is that they're asking us to speculate on a hypothetical situation that didn't actually occur in the movie. They're essentially posing a "What if ______ happened?" type of scenario.
While fun to contemplate, these kinds of purely hypothetical questions don't really align with the Q&A model and scope of the SE network.
So in keeping with our established precedent, I believe the prudent route would be to close the School of Rock legal question as well, since it falls into that same category of hypothetical "what if" questions that we've determined aren't a great fit for this site.

I am in agreement with the answer above. I do however want to make a special plea for not simply closing these questions, but rather encouraging OP to rephrase them to ask whether these characters did ultimately suffer any consequences from their actions.
There are a significant number of resources that are available; sequels, interviews, tie-in novels, etc. that give us information about "what happened next" in films and TV shows that appear to be completed.
So, instead of

"Would Jack Black go to jail?"

we could ask

"Did Jack Black go to jail?"

